# How to know where a syntax was set?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want to know what line and file `syntax region foo start...` was set.

I have tried this:

```
:verbose syntax foo
:syntax foo?
:verbose syntax foo?
```

Comment: One relatively simple, but still slightly manual, way: use `:scriptnames`. You can traverse  quite quickly with `:execute 'args' join(filter(split(execute('scriptnames')), "v:val =~# 'syntax\/'"))` - this will open all loaded script files that match `syntax/`, and the file you want is probably one of these.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg another way is to use rip grep. Usually you would go in $VIMRUNTIME or in ~/.vim ```rg 'something'```. I just thought there was a command I could use from vim to find out.

Comment: I don't think there is (but I'll be glad to learn otherwise). However, there is `:verbose highlight Group`, which _may_ help if the default highlighting is added in the same file/location.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Ya, that's usually where I start. More of then than not the one that does the syntax match is the one that does the highlight also. Not always the case though.